# How to make automated backup of a firebase storage bucket with firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have an app located in firebase. I can backup daily firestore collections with functions but I also need to back up storage bucket with the same syncronisation. Because firestore has connections to storage. Both of them should be done consequently with functions. Otherwise restored data can have broken links to storage. Because I my forgot to create a daily storage backup manually.

I tried on Google and Google dox but couldn't find an automated solution.